# Does JPA have something like hibernates '@GenericGenerator' for generating custom ids?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to create a custom way of computing and passing unique id's that follow my own pattern.

Hibernate has the @GenericGenerator annotation that lets you map a custom class for computing a unique id and assigning it back to the @Id column.

example

```
  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(generator="MyIdGenerator")
  @GenericGenerator(name="MyIdGenerator", strategy="com.test.MyIdGenerator")
```

The thing is that i don't want to use (hibernates) @GenericGenerator at package level.
Can this be in "pure" JPA / 2 ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it doesn't have. Only possibility without 3rd party is to assign value by yourself. If you want to save yourself from calling method that sets id, then for example Prepersist callback can be used.

```
  @PrePersist
  public void ensureId() {
    id = ...
  }
```

Comment: Very elegant solution indeed. Is it really allowed? the specification is ambiguous when it states:  In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager
or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the
same persistence context[46].
[47] A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship
state of the entity on which it is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EclipseLink, you can define your own custom Sequence object.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomSequencing

JPA 2.0 does not define a custom sequence generator, but JPA 2.1 does define a Converter API, which may be of use.

Comment: Converter can't be used for Id

Comment: That's the question I'm asking. The EclipseLink sequence object may be the answer for me then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613929/jpa-tablegenerator-does-not-allow-for-data-type-converter