# @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign") to standard JPA 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I would like to know if there is a standard way to convert something like that

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

to standard JPA 2 model without hibernate

EDit : lets see both entities (i've only keep the annoted interessting portion)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author", catalog = "test")
public class Author implements java.io.Serializable {

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }
```

AND

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "test")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Author getAuthor() {
        return this.author;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does JPA have something like hibernates '@GenericGenerator' for generating custom ids?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461878/does-jpa-have-something-like-hibernates-genericgenerator-for-generating-custo)

Comment: what is the use of  parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user")) ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want those entities to have the exact same Id. If so just add in Author Class

```
 @OneToOne @MapsId
        public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }
```

The `@MapsId` annotation will do the trick. You can check there http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html (example 2)

Answer (score 1):

I only use JPA model so I'm not sure if this is linked to a serial (sequence). If so, then it should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project", schema = "a_schema" )
@SequenceGenerator(name = "project_id_seq_generator", sequenceName = "a_schema.project_id_sequence")
public class MyObject {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "project_id_seq_generator")
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private Long projectID;
//...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but nope its a foreign key (a one to one relation key)

Comment: I don't know if is possible but maybe you could try using the @OneToOne(mappedBy=...) annotation and/or the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation. See this example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/OneToOneMappedBy.htm

Comment: I've add the 2 entities to better understand the need

Comment: Well, I really think it isn't possible using pure JPA. What you could do is use the OneToOne and maybe a PrePersist to set the id.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461878/does-jpa-have-something-like-hibernates-genericgenerator-for-generating-custo